# Defining functions in FOL + PA

Tags: lo.logic

I am looking into the practicalities of doing Math in FOL + PA with the FOL extended with equality and functions.

For a predicate you can easily extend the language such that a predicate is defined as a logical expression, which then can be comprehended or expanded in the proofs and theorems that follow.

However, if you want to do the same for a function, then it should be proven that the function is deterministic (giving only one result for a certain set of parameters) and total. If you define the function with other functions, then it that is obvious. However, if the function is defined using logical expressions then it is not obvious.

If I look in the literature I see often a function popping up (such as Gödel's β function) without this explicit proof. I assume that it has informally proven, but since I want to write a piece of text about this, my question is if there are any conventions how to deal with this and how you normally incorporate this in a logic language that can checked by a theorem checker?

This is not very theoretical, since you can get rid of function and rewrite the expressions as predicates.

Thanks in advance,

Lucas

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what specifically you're looking for in an answer. Are you looking for a proof that the $\beta$-function is in fact single-valued?

Comment: No, that is quite obvious. My question is how do theorem checkers in general deal with this? So, I see suddenly a new function, but not defined in such way that it can de described in a formal language.

Comment: "I see suddenly a new function, but not defined in such way that it can described in a formal language." My instinct is that the first thing to do is ... describe it in a formal language. Do you have a concrete example of this? I'm still confused what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: For instance, if you define the remainder function, you can define it as predicate as follows: $R(x, y, z) = z < y \land \exists v: x = vy + z$ However, if you have FOL extended with functions, what is the normal notation to make that a function? That should only be allowed if the function is single-valued and total (otherwise, certain axioms are not valid).

Comment: Are you perhaps thinking of the Hilbert epsilon, which is conservative over FOL?

Comment: Shoenfield's book "Mathematical Logic" treats extensions (of FO theories) by definitions in Section 4.6, defines the beta function and (informally but carefully) proves its relevant properties in Section 6.4, and explains how to formalize all this in Section 8.1.

Comment: Thanks, I have that book, I will take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might avoid the issue in first-order arithmetic by assuming that a function always selects the least option, or zero if there is no option. So a definition like
$$R(x,y,z)=z<y \wedge \exists v:x = vy+z$$
would actually be transformed into
$$R'(x,y,z)=(R(x,y,z) \wedge \forall w:R(x,y,w)\implies z\le w) \vee (z=0 \wedge \forall z: \neg R(x,y,z))$$

Alternatively, you might follow Solomon Feferman in using logical frameworks flexible enough to include symbols for partial functions and for [definedness](https://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/%7Efeferman/papers/definedness.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, so, basically if you are creating a checker, you have two directions you can go. When introducing a function the user must provide a proof that it is well-defined, or enforce it by construction (which seems to be more standard). Still, in literature and student material, IMHO, don't propose functions in FOL at all, or also cover this aspect, but don't do half a job.